# Get Properties from Member in Umbraco programmatically

Tags: umbraco

I thought this would be really simple but ..

We've create a user and a member type with various properties
When we try to access the properties via the member object we got nothing.

//Member m is current User

eg. 
Property  s = m.getProperty("PreferdUserName");
is null

m.getProperties has a count of Zero..

have we missed something obvious?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
Property s = m.getProperty("PreferdUserName").value;
```

If that still doesn't work, then check out this great post about member properties

http://legacy.aaron-powell.com/blog/july-2009/umbraco-member-profiles.aspx

Comment: I don't think this is valid anymore (umbraco 4.5 and up) and the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Could there be a spelling error?

"PreferdUserName" may want to be "PreferredUserName".

Other than that it looks correct.

Comment: i had checked that one as well :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end i resorted to storing member properties in a separate db table, which anyhow is closer to what i need. 
I presume it had something to do with the way I created the memberType from outside umbraco using a custom msbuild task.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own class and extend ProfileBase. The code below will expose the properties that you have created within Umbraco. e.g. umbraco alias is 'first_name'.

```
[SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
public string FirstName
{
    get
    {
        var o = base.GetPropertyValue("first_name");
        if (o == DBNull.Value)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return (string)o;
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetPropertyValue("first_name", value);
    }
}
```

Then you can access properties like so...

```
string firstName = ((MemberProfile)HttpContext.Current.Profile).FirstName;
```

More info about how to set this all up can be seen here:

http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2010-04-07-umbraco-members-profiles.html

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone else, if you need to get member details for someone other than the current user in Umbraco and have their Username.

```
var TheirUsername = "s12345";

Member MemberFind = new Member(Convert.ToInt32(Membership.GetUser(***TheirUsername***).ProviderUserKey));

//now use this value

var NameOfUser = MemberFind.Text;

var EmailAddress = MemberFind.Email;
```